# Conductivity monitoring to detect integrity loss of glass coating of steel

Tags: instrumentation, conductivity

I have an application where the integrity of the glass lining of a  glass coated steel vessel needs to be monitored.

In theory, once the integrity is lost anywhere there ought to be contact between the fluid inside the vessel and the underlying steel. The fluid inside is conductive, say water with salts in it.

In practice, would one be able to monitor the conductivity change and trigger an alarm?

To make the problem specific, say the vessel is 10,000 L capacity (cylindrical) and the glass lining is 2 mm thick (if that matters). Is it realistic to be able to detect a lining breach by monitoring conductivity?

Any other ideas for a detection system?

Alternatively, could the capacitance of the liquid-glass-steel or the air-glass-steel system be monitored? Would one expect the capacitance to change significantly if the glass gets a small breach?

***To add more context:***

If the breach in glass lining is detected early enough then there are ways to patch it up. Hence the goal is to try and catch the breach as small as you can. There's no breach that's too small since these linings are used in corrosive environments the smallest breach will allow the corrosive fluid to progressively eat away the underlying steel and then widen the breach.

i.e. It's only a matter of time for a small breach to turn into a large breach.

Comment: It doesn't sound completely unrealistic.  Relatively high voltage may be required for this test, though.  (By the way, condoms are tested like that.)

Comment: Can the vessel be tested without the conductive liquid? Is there an open access to the surface? I am afraid that there could be micro-crack defects that might present relatively high impedance, so the bulk method you suggested might not detect them.

Comment: In principal this should be "easy", a simple DC continuity tester should do it.  Just enter "continuity tester" into Bing images.  The electrode in the water should probably be a stainless steel rod.  Other metals might corrode.   The high capacitance of the tank might bring up some non-obvious problem.  I can imagine other problems, a small flaw might be too small for a simple continuity tester to detect it at first.

Comment: @RobertEndl Thanks. Yes, in principle. I've used continuity testers and in fact that's what sparked the idea. The question is whether the difference in effective condictivites of the electrode-in-water scenario (with & without glass damage) would be large enough for easy detection. Trying to calculate / estimate that.

Comment: @AliChen Yes.  Testing without the liquid is possible. What methods might you suggest? Thoughts?

Comment: @NickAlexeev Thanks! We already use something like the condom testing method: It's called a spark tester. A person with the device physically enters the vessel and using a high voltage electrode passess over every area of the glass. If there's a breach then a spark will strike. But that's a very labor intensive slow method and needs each area to be examined piece by piece. I was hoping a conductivity based method might provide an alternative. At least to know there's a breach after which the high V spark tester can be used to localize the problem spot.

Comment: Curious_Cat...I was afraid of that.  We have used a HV source to find cracks in molded plastic bodies for sensors.  However, we had to dip the body in water, kind of the reverse of what you are doing now.  This method did find tiny (but fatal) flaws other methods could not.  One of our customers put us on to this.

Answer (score 2):

An interesting problem.
I seriously doubt that a continuity test will suffice for your application. 
This would require that you have a large enough fault in the glass surface to actually touch the outer container. I'd imagine that you may have a class of faults that are just cracks or blemishes that could only be detected by a Hi-pot leakage test.

There are plenty of [commercial Hi-pot testers](http://www.elsinco.com/images/doku/TOS8870A.pdf) that should meet you need.

If you want to roll your own (inadvisable, though would be fun) then you could use something like a CO2 Laser power supply (20kV) with an optically isolated high side current detector (very high side!!).
The dialectic strength of air is much less than that of glass (though your glass type is not specified). So if you position a high voltage ball probe at 3-4 mm above the glass you should be able to identify high leakage areas as faults.

[image]

Comment: But for the pot testing one would have to enter the empty vessel and physically check areas of the glass wall for dielectric strength, right? One can't use that to routinely monitor lining integrity of the entire tank online?

Comment: @curious_cat. No matter what you use you have to put some form of probe in the tank. Drain the tank and you could Hi-Pot test. Now if the tank needed to be tested while full and the fluid was conductive; perhaps you could perform a gross resistivity test. But here you'd have to be able to isolate the fluid completely from the tank outer steel sheath. eg. in a home water heater, the fluid connects to the sheath (I assume) at entry, exit and electrical connectors. If it does not, then that could be a gross test, but it does not tell you where the flaw is.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking at some form of a "gross" test. Something which can sure have a probe in tank but something that does not need one to sweep every inch of tank surface with a probe.

Comment: A test which will work with a full tank is preferred, but something that works with an empty tank is also OK so long as it is just a probe that does not need to be manually sweeped on the full tank surface. The test only needs to *detect* a breach & not to identify the breach location.

Comment: How much (%) would you expect the gross resistivity to change on a breach.  If specifics help, say a dime (coin) sized breach in a 10,000 Litre tank with a 2 mm glass coating on a 8 mm steel tank wall.

Comment: @curious_cat. If the tank is full and perfect you have a resistor (the fluid) and a capacitor (fluid - steel case) in series. If you have a flaw, then you have a resistor in parallel with the capacitor. You'd have to test it out to see whether you could discern flaws from this. But I depends on the steel case being completely isolated....is it? One thought would be to put a grounded probe in the fluid, and try to raise the potential of the steel shield and measure current flow or capacitance/resistance.